Oracle connector configuration in ElasticSearch
According to the elastic documentation and source code on the github you have to connected to SID, which in my opinion does not make sense, because it is outdated, I would prefer to connect using service-name which means service-based connection, is it possible to do it, couldn't find any different parameter which I could use instead of database=....
class OracleDataSource(BaseDataSource):
    """Oracle Database"""

    name = "Oracle Database"
    service_type = "oracle"

    def __init__(self, configuration):
        """Setup connection to the Oracle database-server configured by user

        Args:
            configuration (DataSourceConfiguration): Instance of DataSourceConfiguration class.
        """
        super().__init__(configuration=configuration)
        self.database = self.configuration["database"]
        self.oracle_client = OracleClient(
            host=self.configuration["host"],
            port=self.configuration["port"],
            user=self.configuration["username"],
            password=self.configuration["password"],
            database=self.configuration["database"],
            tables=self.configuration["tables"],
            protocol=self.configuration["oracle_protocol"],
            oracle_home=self.configuration["oracle_home"],
            wallet_config=self.configuration["wallet_configuration_path"],
            retry_count=self.configuration["retry_count"],
            fetch_size=self.configuration["fetch_size"],
            logger_=self._logger,
        )

    def _set_internal_logger(self):
        self.oracle_client.set_logger(self._logger)

I tried connecting using connection string to sid, but I got error username/password and when I try using servicename I get cannot connect to database (Similar to ORA-12505).

Can you fork oracle.py and change SID to SERVICE_NAME in the elasticsearch code?
